# sqlite-net-pcl CreateTableAsync in Xamarin Android throws the error 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException'

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm having a Xamarin native devlopment solution. It includes a couple of projects, a PCL project and a Xamarin.Android project.

I installed [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) for the PCL project and I am passing the platform specific database location path from the android project to the PCL. The folder path sets properly and when the execution head executes,

```
database.CreateTableAsync<MyModel>().Wait();

public class MyModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

It throws,

```
Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown. An unhandled exception occured.
```

and crashes. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can appear if the **Model** class is containing any non complex data types like Arrays or Lists. The plugin supports only non complex types like, **int, bool, string, enum ...**. The Model class is not having an issue here.

I solved this problem by,

1. installing the [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) package for the **android project** as well.
2. Cleaning the solution.
3. **Deleting** the **bin** and **obj** folders of the android project.

then running the application after these steps, the app started functioning well

Comment: installing the sqlite-net-pcl package for the android project as well. <-- this solved my problem.